# Look up missing values in lookup table in SAS

Tags: sas, lookup

I have a table that looks like this

```
(MAIN TABLE)
====================================================================================
|| TRANSACTION_ID || TRADE_PARTY_PREFIX || TRADE_PARTY_VALUE || TRADE_PARTY_TYPE
====================================================================================
| 1               | EXAMPLE             | 123456789           | Dealer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2               | EXAMPLE             | 123456789           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3               | EXAMPLE_2           | 123456789           | Non-Dealer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4               | EXAMPLE             | 987654321           |
```

I have another table that looks like this

```
(LOOKUP TABLE)
=================================================================
|| TRADE_PARTY_PREFIX || TRADE_PARTY_VALUE || TRADE_PARTY_TYPE ||
=================================================================
| EXAMPLE             | 123456789           | Dealer
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| EXAMPLE             | 987654321           | Dealer
```

I want to have a SAS script that replaces all the missing values in the `TRADE_PARTY_TYPE` by looking up the `TRADE_PARTY_PREFIX` and `TRADE_PARTY_VALUE` in the lookup table (but it should not touch the row if that column is already filled in.

Something along the lines of (in pseudo-code):

```
for row in main_table:
    if row["trade_party_type"] is not null:
        print(row)
    else
        row["trade_party_type"] == lookup_table["trade_party_prefix"]["trade_party_value"]
```

Not sure how to do this in SAS.

Comment: Perhaps a quick google of "SAS table lookup" would be in order.

Comment: The examples I find either hard code the choices `(if part_num = 1 then part_name = "brakes")`, which is impractical in this case, or they replace the values in the column outright (using a `MERGE` or a SQL join statement).  However, I only want the values replaced if the value is empty.

Comment: The first hit in Google for those search terms (for me) shows four techniques, two of which could be trivially used for your purpose (ie, in an `if` statement, but not hardcoded values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `coalesce` function in a `PROC SQL` step like so:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE WANT AS 
        SELECT a.transaction_id, a.trade_party_prefix, a.trade_party_value, coalesce(a.trade_party_type,b.trade_party_type) AS trade_party_type
            FROM dset1 a LEFT JOIN dset2 b
                ON a.trade_party_prefix = b.trade_party_prefix AND a.trade_party_value = b.trade_party_value;
QUIT;
```

The coalesce function evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.